# Set time connection and disconnection of the charger [android]

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to create application that controls the connection of the phone to the charger. The application should remember the time of connecting and disconnection of the charger.
To storage the data i'm using Shared Preferences. I'm using broadcast receiver to control when device is charging.

This is my broadcast:

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        SharedPreferences pref;

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 

            pref = context.getSharedPreferences("StatusOfCharging",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = pref.edit();

                int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);         
                boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                        status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

                prefEditor.putBoolean("isCharging", false).commit();

                if (isCharging == true){
                    Log.d("daf", "work");

                }else{
                    prefEditor.putBoolean("isCharging", false).commit();

                }

                int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);

                boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
                boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;

        }
}
```

Do anybody have an idea how to remember charging time ?

Comment: You could do `prefEditor.putLong("start_charging", System.currentTimeMillis());` when you start charging and `prefEditor.putLong("end_charging", System.currentTimeMillis());` when you are done. Then to check duration and stuff like that just do `duration = prefEditor.getLongExtra("end_charging") - prefEditor.getLongExtra("start_charging");`

Comment: Thanks. But now I get an error that getLongExra is undefinde for SharedPreferences.Editor.

Comment: Sorry, prefEditor.getLong("start_charging", 0L);